# Sublime Text 2 with Pandas for Excel (Combining Data) & Data Visualization

Tags: machine-learning, python, pandas, numpy

I'm new to programming with Python, and so far it's been a headache to create a build environment- and need your support and expertise in this area.

Background I'm running a MacBook, and using Sublime Text 2, and needing to learn python. I'd like to finish this tutorial on youtube on Data Science (manipulating excel files really "aggregating data on excel"- i'll post the link below and need to import pandas- but apparently I can't.

Also, worth mentioning; I'll also be using Numpy, Xlrd, Matplotlib in the future, and not sure if these modules are available on Sublime Text 2.

The Challenge:

When I run this line, I get an error.

`import pandas as pd`

I have researched the problem, and it seems that I don't have package control on my sublime text and found this site with the package control addition- so here's the website that I found with a long code to download the package.

https://packagecontrol.io/installation#st2

1) Is this a legit site to download this software?

2) Can I even add these modules to Sublime Text 2 to do Data Science & view excel documents

3) If I add this installation "package control", will this package allow me to download pandas, and other modules into Sublime Text 2

4) If Yes, where can I find instructions for installing the Pandas/Numpy/Xlrd modules?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4_BPNnKEMn8

Comment: Use Anaconda:
https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sublime Text is a text editor - it is independent of your Python setup. I would suggest following a tutorial on setting up Anaconda on your machine, then follow a second tutorial on making sublime text find the Anaconda Python executable.

- Here is a tutorial for [**setting up Python with Anaconda on a Mac**](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/installing-anaconda-mac-os-x).
- Here is [**something I found with a simple search**](https://gist.github.com/zaemiel/4fbd8b5125fda7a140be) (disclaimer: I don't know anything about sublime text!)

Once you have anaconda installed, you would need to run this command in terminal to install the packages you need:

```
conda install numpy pandas xlrd matplotlib
```

Comment: Thank you for that!  I had previously installed python and anaconda on my mac but wasn't able to figure out how to download the packages- and couldn't figure out why when I downloaded the 3.6 version, why Python 2.7.10 was installed on my Mac. I thought I did something wrong- my terminal python --version and I get 2.7.10.  I think I wen't down a rabbit hole. But, I just updated conda from 4.710 to 4.7.12. THANK YOU! For sublime, I had it processing python already- but easily switching over to Anaconda. I couldn't import pandas and couldn't figure out why using anaconda. I think you solved it.

Comment: What other packages would you recommend that I download for what I'm trying to accomplish-V/Hlookups, Index/Match, and or combining excel files,  Pivot Tables, Cleaning/Sorting Data, things like that. Also, I'm trying to create a script using python to log into a website- type in certain info- and download a file, save it to desktop- copy the .csv file convert it to xls file type- then run a sort, total, then pivot the data. Or another task that I need it for is to automate a SQL or Access Query to pull data-. I'm very new as you can tell, and not sure of Anaconda's capabilities.

Comment: Dang! It works- just ran my first data frame using anaconda! THANK YOU!

Comment: @Laythesmack - you're welcome :) Pandas will be able to do all of your basic analysis. If you installed Anaconda (not Miniconda), then it will already contain a multude of packages that might be useful! Please mark the question as solved!